# SQL query based on column condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table in which below are the columns.  I'm using sql server.

Id, name, device and information on if device is active or not.

Need to have a SQL query for below scenario:

I want to display `firstdevice`, `seconddevice` columns below based on `isActive` column. If `isACTIVE` is `1` then, fill the device name in `firstdevice` column, if `isActive` is `0` then fill the device name in `secondDevice`.

| Id | name | firstDevice | secondDevice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Motorola | phone | tablet |

Comment: The functionality you are after is called `PIVOT`. Can you share what RDBMS you are you using so we can better guide (each RDBMS has a different syntax for making this happen).

Comment: Can you add more samples? Can we get `1, motorola, 1, laptop`?

Comment: Is it possible for there to be more than 2 devices? Fewer? How would you handle, say, an id with only an inactive device?

Comment: Add the <sql-server> tag from the beginning when you ask your next question. Don't waste helpful people's time writing answers for other dbms's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, name, 
MAX(CASE when isActive = 1 then device end) AS firstDevice,
MAX(CASE when isActive = 0 then device end) AS secondDevice
from table
group by 
id, name
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have only maximum 2 rows per id and name

```
select id, name, 
MAX(DECODE(isActive, 1, device)) AS firstDevice,
MAX(DECODE(isActive, 0, device)) AS secondDevice
from table
group by 
id, name;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using sql server. Please tell me query compatible for sql server.

Comment: In that case use `CASE when` instead of `DECODE`.